# Lenovo Bluetooth Mouse Freezes During Use

Tags: xubuntu, bluetooth, mouse, thinkpad, blueman

Help! I bought my wife the mouse of her dreams, and it doesn't work correctly. It pairs without any issue and never disconnects, but at some point during use (after 5-30 minutes), it completely stops responding (while staying connected according to Blueman). If I try to disconnect and reconnect with Blueman, it fails to respond to the "disconnect" command at all, and I'm forced to reboot. Then, it works again for another 5-30 minutes before freezing.

This does not seem to be related to "idling," as it happens randomly during active use.

System details:

- Lenovo ThinkPad Bluetooth Silent Mouse 4Y50X88822 (https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/p/accessories-and-software/keyboards-and-mice/mice/4y50x88822)
- Lenovo ThinkPad X220
- Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 73) WiFi network (and Bluetooth) card/controller
- Xubuntu 22.04

Tried and failed:

- Battery replacement
- Pairing manually via bluetoothctl (and disabling Blueman)
- Setting UserspaceHID=true in /etc/bluetooth/input.conf

Any ideas are greatly appreciated!

---

EDIT - MORE INFO BELOW...

More things I tried that did not work:

- Used same PC and mouse under Xubuntu 23.04 with newer Linux kernel 6.2.0-20-generic (original 22.04 kernel was 5.15.0-71-generic)
- Checked if I had TLP installed because someone said it can cause Bluetooth problems (it was not installed at all; moot point)
- Turned off PCI Express power management in system BIOS (note that this WiFi/Bluetooth combo card is in a mini PCI-e slot)
- Taped over pin 20 on the mini PCI-e card (note that I already taped over pin 51 to make Bluetooth work in the first place)

Other notes:

- Whenever the mouse freezes, suspending the computer and then waking it up immediately makes the mouse work again. Same for rebooting.

Comment: @guiverc Thanks for the suggestion! I know how to boot from a live USB, but I'm afraid I don't know how to make a manual kernel stack choice. Any clarification/instructions would be appreciated.

Comment: @guiverc My existing 22.04 installation uses kernel 5.15.0-71-generic. I booted to a Xubuntu 23.04 live USB using kernel 6.2.0-20-generic, and the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

Very bizarre hack of a solution:

The mouse would never, ever play nice with the Intel 7260 card (even though Bluetooth audio with wireless speakers works great and never disconnects, btw), so we bought a TP-Link UB400 USB Bluetooth dongle ([https://www.amazon.com/TP-Link-Bluetooth-Receiver-Controllers-UB400/dp/B07V1SZCY6/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07V1SZCY6)), which was instantly 100% perfectly compatible with Linux and the mouse. Since dongles are ugly, we hid it INSIDE the computer with a special internal USB port adapter made specifically for the ThinkPad X220 (https://www.aliexpress.us/item/3256802303543150.html).

Now the computer has 2 bluetooth adapters, which Blueman handles simultaneously very elegantly. You can select which devices to connect to through which adapters easily in the GUI. The mouse auto-reconnects through the correct adapter every time, and has been working seamlessly for days.